# How to avoid user having to re-authorize Evernote every time?

Tags: python-2.7, evernote

I'm building a Python web app with the Evernote API. When users log in they're redirected to a page on the Evernote site to authorize the application. When they come back everything works fine (can see and edit notes etc.)

The challenge now is to avoid having to redirect the user to the Evernote site every time they log on.

I read on the [Evernote forums](https://discussion.evernote.com/topic/27628-storing-user-credentials-for-access/) that I need to save the access token and the notestore url to achieve this. I now save these to the users accounts after the first successful authorization.

But how do I use the access token and notestore url to authorize?

I found this sample code on the Evernote website that's supposed to achieve this, but it's in Java and I can't seem to make it work in Python.

```
// Retrieved during authentication:  
String authToken = ...  
String noteStoreUrl = ...  

String userAgent = myCompanyName + " " + myAppName + "/" + myAppVersion;  

THttpClient noteStoreTrans = new THttpClient(noteStoreUrl);  
userStoreTrans.setCustomHeader("User-Agent", userAgent);  
TBinaryProtocol noteStoreProt = new TBinaryProtocol(noteStoreTrans);  
NoteStore.Client noteStore = new NoteStore.Client(noteStoreProt, noteStoreProt);
```

Basically, if you got the notestore url and access token from a previous authorization, how do you use them to re-authorize?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have the access token, you will use that as a constructor argument for the `EvernoteClient` class.

For example:

```
client = EvernoteClient(token=your_access_token)
note_store = client.get_note_store()
notebooks = note_store.listNotebooks();
for n in notebooks:
    print n.name
```

For more examples, check out the [Python Quick-start Guide](https://dev.evernote.com/doc/start/python.php).

Comment: I tried this again never thinking it would work... but this time it did! I saved the access token in the database and using it I can now skip the authentication redirect. Thanks for the help! :-) I got really confused by some Evernote forum posts.